# linear algebra applied in discrete Markov Process

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, markov-process

We give an abstract description of the discrete Markov process as follows: Consider a system $A$ with $n$-possible states: $S_{1},\ S_{2},\cdots, S_{n}$. In each step of this process, the system randomly alters from one state to another. We use the notation $A(k)= S_{l}$ to denote the event $A$ is in state $S_{l}$ in step $k$.'' Suppose the change of $A$ satisfies the following rule:
     Assume $A(k)= S_{i}$. Then 
     $$
 \text{Probability}(A(k+1)= S_{j})=t_{i,j}
 $$
     This number $t_{i,j}$ does not depend on $k$.  We define the transition matrix $T\in M(n,n)$ by setting its $(i,j)$th entry to be $t_{i,j}$. In other words, $T_{i,j}=t_{i,j}$.
Now suppose we know that $A(0)=S_{1}$. We consider the \textbf{row vector}
$$
\vec{v}_{k}=[\text{Probability}(A(k)= S_{1}),\ \text{Probability}(A(k)= S_{2}),\cdots,\  \text{Probability}(A(k)= S_{n})].
$$
Show that for any positive integer $k$, we have 
$$\vec{v}_{k}=[1,0,\cdots, 0]\cdot T^{k}.$$

Comment: Hint: Use induction. (For example, try it with $k=1$ and $k=2$.